# How to allow external network to use my squid proxy

Tags: squid

I've seen too many articles on how to install and configure **squid**, but most of them are written how to configure it in the local network. I'm going to create **public** forward proxy server, so:

- I have **installed** squid  on Linode Centos 7 instance,
- Service is **running**
- Squid uses 3128 port and it is **open** from outside the network

Now, from my **home**, I try to change proxy settings in Firefox but I have still my home IP.

1. I have written  **acl all src all** to the top of your ACL list.
2. I have changed **http_access deny** all  to  **http_access allow all**
3. I've tested and 3128 port is accessible from my home PC

Is there anything else that I should do? have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in this step:

> Now, from my home, I try to change proxy settings in Firefox but I have still my home IP.

If the server still shows your home IP, it seems Firefox doesn't use your proxy. Try to stop your proxy and see whether Firefox complains that the proxy is unavailable.

If firefox does use your proxy, try this setting in squid.conf

```
forwarded_for off
```

Comment: Everything seems well in Firefox.  I've tested this config, but does not works :(